# action script 3.0 import fla with xml

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

*i want import fla movie from xml*. i can't make it. Thank for help.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.engine.TabAlignment;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
```

//i create timer for sound.

```
var tmr:Timer=new Timer(1000,1);
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sesiBaslat);
function sesiBaslat(evt:TimerEvent){

    var yol:URLRequest=new URLRequest("../../../sound/aaa/1/1/1.mp3");
    var ses:Sound=new Sound();
    ses.load(yol);
    ses.play();
}
tmr.start();
```

//i was use this code in old times

```
/*var vid:Video = new Video(1600, 910);
flvPlaceHolder.addChild(vid);
addChild(flvPlaceHolder);
flvPlaceHolder.x = stage.stageWidth/2-vid.width/2;
flvPlaceHolder.y = stage.stageHeight/2-vid.height/2;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;
ns.play("fla/683-bak.flv");

*/
```

//now i want to write this format now,because i want to make it dynamic
    var veriler:XML;

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLokundu);
loader.load(new URLRequest("../../../xml/aaa/1/1/1.xml"));

function XMLokundu(e:Event):void{

        veriler= new XML(e.target.data);

        var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
        loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
        loader1.load(new URLRequest(veriler.animasyonlar.animasyon[1].yolu));
```

//This blog was made a import sound,image etc. but doesnt work from fla

```
            function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
        var flvPlaceHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var vid:Video = new Video();
        e.target.content.smoothing = true;
        addChild(loader1);
        loader1.x = veriler.animasyonlar.animasyon[1].xkor;
        loader1.y = veriler.animasyonlar.animasyon[1].ykor;
        loader1.width = veriler.animasyonlar.animasyon[1].width;
        loader1.height = veriler.animasyonlar.animasyon[1].height;
    }
}
```

/*
             //XML FİLE

//This is my xml file

```
<animasyonlar>
        <animasyon>
        <first>sound/16/1153.mp3</first>
        <ikincises>sound/16/1154.mp3</ikincises>
        <ucuncuses>sound/16/1151.mp3</ucuncuses>
        <dorduncuses>sound/16/1152.mp3</dorduncuses>
        <yolu>../../../../bbb/7/fla/683-look.flv</yolu>  1.fla way
        <xkor>800</xkor> 2.x value
        <ykor>100</ykor> 3.y value
        <width>50%</width>
        <height>50%</height>
        </animasyon>
        </animsyonlar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not formatted properly because your closing tag is missing the 2nd "a".

```
<animasyonlar>
...
</animsyonlar>
```